# python csv.read seams to find more newlines

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I use python3 and I try to parse a csv string, which I got from a urllib response.

After decoding the string looks as follows:

```
"s","p","o"
"http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid","http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat"
```

edit: `print(repr(responseString))` gives me:

```
'"s","p","o"\n"http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid","http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat"\n'
```

but after running `resultSet = csv.reader(responseString)` and printing the result with following loop:

```
for row in resultSet:
    print(row)
```

it shows me following result:

```
['s']
['', '']
['p']
['', '']
['o']
[]
['http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid']
['', '']
['http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type']
['', '']
['http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat']
[]
```

which doesn't seam correct. Especially I'm wondering, where these empty rows (`['', '']`) are coming from.

edit2: According to my understanding of CSV, I would expect something like:

```
['s', 'p', 'o']
['http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type', 'http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat']
```

Comment: It means that row is empty

Comment: Your string parses just fine. Can you post what `repr(the_string)` outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

csv.reader iterates through the object it is given, and interprets each item as a line (which works well with file descriptors).
However, you are giving it a string, and iterating through a string… gives characters.

You should instead pass it directly the socket object or, if you can't, do it like this:

```
resultSet = csv.reader(responseString.split('\n'))
```

Comment: there is also `.splitlines()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) (in the io module in Py3; it own module in Py2) to turn a string into a file like object:

```
txt='"s","p","o"\n"http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid","http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat"\n'

import csv
from io import StringIO

for line in csv.reader(StringIO(txt)):
    print(line)
```

Prints:

```
['s', 'p', 'o']
['http://www.openlinksw.com/virtrdf-data-formats#default-iid', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type', 'http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat']
```